# Publisher emitting progress of operation and final value

Tags: swift, combine

Given I have an SDK which provides the functionality below

```
class SDK {
    static func upload(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            completion(.success("my_value"))
        }
    }
}
```

I am able to a create a wrapper around to make its usage more functional

```
class CombineSDK {
    func upload() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> {
        Future { promise in
            SDK.upload { result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let key):
                    promise(.success(key))
                case .failure(let error):
                    promise(.failure(error))
                }
            }
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to understand how my CombineSDK.upload method should look like if the SDK upload method also provides a progress block like below:

```
class SDK {
    static func upload(progress: @escaping (Double) -> Void, completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
            progress(0.5)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            progress(1)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            completion(.success("s3Key"))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need an `Output` type for your publisher that represents either the progress, or the final value. So we should use an `enum`. Since the Foundation framework already defines a type named `Progress`, we'll name ours `Progressable` to avoid a name conflict. We might as well make it generic:

```
enum Progressable<Value> {
    case progress(Double)
    case value(Value)
}
```

Now we need to think about how the publisher should behave. A typical publisher, like [`URLSession.DataTaskPublisher`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/6364a9912307528827702a39dc85e523927f6423/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BURLSession.swift), doesn't **do** anything until it gets a subscription, and it starts its work fresh for each subscription. The [`retry`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/retry(_:)) operator only works if the upstream publisher behaves like this.

So our publisher should behave that way, too:

```
extension SDK {
    static func uploadPublisher() -> UploadPublisher {
        return UploadPublisher()
    }

    struct UploadPublisher: Publisher {
        typealias Output = Progressable<String>
        typealias Failure = Error

        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
            <#code#>
        }
    }
}
```

Creating the publisher (by calling `SDK.uploadPublisher()`) doesn't start any work. We'll replace `<#code#>` with code to start the upload:

```
extension SDK {
    static func uploadPublisher() -> UploadPublisher {
        return UploadPublisher()
    }

    struct UploadPublisher: Publisher {
        typealias Output = Progressable<String>
        typealias Failure = Error

        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
            let subject = PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>()
            subject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)

           upload(
                progress: { subject.send(.progress($0)) },
                completion: {
                    switch $0 {
                    case .success(let value):
                        subject.send(.value(value))
                        subject.send(completion: .finished)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        subject.send(completion: .failure(error))
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we call `subject.receive(subscriber: subscriber)` **before** we start the upload. This is important! What if `upload` calls one of its callbacks synchronously, before returning? By passing the subscriber to the subject before calling upload, we ensure that the subscriber has the chance to be notified even if `upload` calls its callbacks synchronously.

Comment: I was just writing a largely similar answer wrt to waiting for subscription and returning an enum. You don't need a whole new custom publisher - just wrap it in a `Deferred` publisher

Comment: You're right that `Deferred` would also work. You should post your own answer, because I'd like to compare a `Deferred` solution to mine.

Answer (score 1):

> **Note**: started writing an answer that's has a largely similar intent to @robmayoff's answer, but using `Deferred`, so posting here for completeness.

Swift Combine only works with values and errors - there's no separate type for progress. But you can model the progress as part of the output, either as a tuple, as was suggested in another answer, or as a custom enum with both progress and result as cases, which would be my preferred approach.

```
class CombineSDK {
   enum UploadProgress<T> {
      case progress(Double)
      case result(T)
   }
    
   func upload() -> AnyPublisher<UploadProgress<String>, Error> {

      Deferred { () -> AnyPublisher<UploadProgress<String>, Error> in
         let subject = PassthroughSubject<UploadProgress<String>, Error>()

         SDK.upload(
            progress: { subject.send(.progress($0)) },
            completion: { r in
               let _ = r.map(UploadProgress.result).publisher.subscribe(subject)
            })

         return subject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
      }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Based on @robmayoff's comment, the above solution doesn't handle synchronous case where `subject.send` is called before `subject` is returned.

The solution is largely the same, but it does introduce a small complication of having to capture these values, just in case. This can be done with `Record`, which will provide a temporary sink to `subject`

```
func upload() -> AnyPublisher<UploadProgress<String>, Error> {

   Deferred { () -> AnyPublisher<UploadProgress<String>, Error> in
      
      let subject = PassthroughSubject<UploadProgress<String>, Error>()
      
      var recording = Record<UploadProgress<String>, Error>.Recording()  
      subject.sink(
         receiveCompletion: { recording.receive(completion: $0) }, 
         receiveValue: { recording.receive($0) })

      SDK.upload(
         progress: { subject.send(.progress($0)) },
         completion: { r in
            let _ = r.map(UploadProgress.result).publisher.subscribe(subject)
         })
        
      return Record(recording: recording).append(subject).eraseToAnyPublisher()
   }
   .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

Comment: If `SDK.upload` calls its callbacks synchronously, or calls them very quickly on a separate thread, the subscriber won't get the corresponding outputs.

Comment: Didn't know about this Record publisher. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible approach

```
extension CombineSDK {
    func upload() -> AnyPublisher<(Double, String?), Error> {
        let publisher = PassthroughSubject<(Double, String?), Error>()
        SDK.upload(progress: { value in
            publisher.send((value, nil))
        }, completion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let key):
                publisher.send((1.0, key))
                publisher.send(completion: .finished)
            case .failure(let error):
                publisher.send(completion: .failure(error))
            }
        })
        return publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was thinking of as well but I am not a big fan of that tuples. But hey if there aren't any other ways I'll take it.

Comment: Well, if you need two parameters... combine them into some model struct if want instead of tuple. I don't know why the key is need (only in output), so I'd remove String and use only Doubles as values for progress and completions.

Comment: A publisher shouldn't start any work until it receives a subscription. Otherwise, the `retry` operator won't work, and the subscriber could miss the first outputs if `SDK.upload` delivers them synchronously.